# How to print feature-test macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, c++20

C++20 has introduced a concept of predefined feature-test macros that allow checking availability of language and library features (see tables in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

I am writing a simple app that will print the values of some of these macros. To reduce code repetition, I extracted printing to a function-like macro:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define print(feature) std::cout << #feature " : " << feature << '\n'

int main()
{
    print(__cpp_aggregate_bases);
    print(__cpp_aggregate_nsdmi);
    print(__cpp_aggregate_paren_init);
}
```

It turns out however that some of the macros are not defined in my compiler (g++ 11.4.0), e.g. `__cpp_auto_cast` or `__cpp_char`, and the compilation fails.

Is there an elegant way to detect the non-defined macros (preferably inside the `print` macro) without having to resort to a monstrosity like this:

```cpp
#if defined(__cpp_auto_cast)
std::cout << "__cpp_auto_cast : " << __cpp_auto_cast << '\n';
#else
std::cout << "__cpp_auto_cast : undefined\n;
#endif
```

repeated for every feature-test macro?

Comment: There's an example [program](https://godbolt.org/z/1hWT7Wh84) at the bottom of the cppreference page that may be useful. It uses some macro magic to get out of problems if the macro isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you Ted. For some reason I have missed this example program.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth explaining the trick that cppreference uses here.

Consider:

```cpp
#define ONCE(x) #x
#define TWICE(x) ONCE(x)
```

And take some C++20 macro that is defined for latest gcc, `__cpp_using_enum`, and another one that doesn't even exist, `__cpp_no_dangling`:

|  | `__cpp_using_enum` | `__cpp_no_dangling` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ONCE` | `"__cpp_using_enum"` | `"__cpp_no_dangling"` |
| `TWICE` | `"201907L"` | `"__cpp_no_dangling"` |

So `ONCE` is useless, but `TWICE` puts us in a situation where we can differentiate between existing and non-existing and do something interesting about it. If `TWICE(x)` gives you a string that starts with `_`, give it a value of `0`. Otherwise, manually compute the value - here we can rely on the fact that it is always going to be `YYYYMM`.

And that's what the cppreference macro does [in the example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test#Example):

```cpp
// Expect a string that starts with 6-decimal-digits or with '_' (if unsupported)
#define COMPILER_VALUE_INT(n) #n [0] == '_' ? 0 : \
    (#n[5] - '0') + (#n[4] - '0') * 10 + (#n[3] - '0') * 100 + \
    (#n[2] - '0') * 1000 + (#n[1] - '0') * 10000 + (#n[0] - '0') * 100000
#define COMPILER_FEATURE_ENTRY(expect, name) { #name, COMPILER_VALUE_INT(name), expect },
```

The extra indirection into `COMPILER_VALUE_INT` is necessary for the same reason that `TWICE` works but `ONCE` does not.